# Perform a POST with parameters to a php WebService

Tags: android, android-webview

I want my activity to access my web service and pass it some parameters, id and usuario.

If I access from the computer's browser I have no problem, so the webService works correctly, but from the activty it does not show me anything.

I leave you the code to see if someone sees the mitsake:

```
public class ConsultaPDF extends Activity {

    int idPlan;
    String usuario;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_consulta_pdf);

        idPlan = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        String postData = "id="+String.valueOf(idPlan)+"&usuario="+usuario;
        String url = "http://www.miurl.es/ws.php";

        try {
            webview.postUrl(url,postData.getBytes( "UTF-8"));
Log.i("WEBVIEW","Todo fue bien");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding","Encoding Exception" +e.toString());
        }

    }


}
```

here I leave the collection of variables in PHP

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

//**RECOGIDA DE DATOS
//-------------------

$id = $_POST['id'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

...
```

Comment: Did you try a browser on your Android device?

Comment: Which Android version on used device?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the apk on my mobile phone and run the application and it doesn't work.

Compile SDK version 29 and min SDK version 17 in my gradle